# (Google sheets) Query and return multiple tables from url inject

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I use the JSON data from a Google spreadsheet, for 2 mobile applications (iOS and Android). The same information can be outputted using HTML or XML, in this case I am using HTML so the information shown (from the spreadsheet) can be understood by everyone. The only logical way to do this is without Authentication (O’Auth) is through public URL Injects. [Information about what I’m talking can be found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses). In order to understand what I’m asking, you have to actually click the links and see for yourself. I do not know what to “call” some of the things I’m asking as Google’s documation is poor, no fault of my own.

In my app I have a search feature that queries the spreadsheet (USING A URL REQUEST) along the lines of this,

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yyHaR2wihF8gLf40k1jrPfzTZ9uKWJKRmFSB519X8Bc/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select+A,B,C,D,E+where+(B+contains"Cat")&gid=0](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yyHaR2wihF8gLf40k1jrPfzTZ9uKWJKRmFSB519X8Bc/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select%20A,B,C,D,E%20where%20(B%20contains%22Cat%22)&gid=0)

I select my columns (A, B, C, D, and, E) and ask (Google) that only the rows where column B contains the word cat be return. Again I’m stressing the point that this is done via a URL address (inject being the proper term). I CANNOT use almost any function/formulas that would normally work within a spreadsheet like, ArrayFormula or ImportRange. In fact I only access to 10 language clauses (Read link from before). I have a rather well knowledge of spreadsheets and databases, and as the URL method of getting information from them is similar they are in NO way the same thing.

Now, I would like to point out this part within the URL

```
tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select+A,B,C,D,E+where+(B+contains"Cat")&gid=0
```

Type of output, HTML in this case

```
tqx=out:html
```

The start of query

```
&tq=
```

Select columns A-E

```
select+A,B,C,D,E
```

For returning specific information about Cat

```
where+(B+contains"Cat")
```

This is probably the most important part of my question. This is used for specifying what table (Tab) is being queried.

```
&gid=0
```

If the gid is changed from gid=0 to gid=181437435 the data returned is from the spreadsheets second table. Instead of having to make 2 requests to search both tables is there a way to do both in one request? (like combining the 2) <— THIS IS WHAT I’M ASKING.

There is a AND clause that I have tried all over the url

```
select+A,B,C,D,E+where+(B+contains%20"Cat")&gid=181437435+AND+select+A,B,C,D,E+where+(B+contains%20"Cat")&gid=0
```

I have even flipped the `gid` around and put in other places but it seems to only go by the last one (gid) in the url, and no matter what is done only 1 table is returned. Grouping is allowed by the way. If that doesn’t clear my question up then let me know where you’re lost. Also I would have posted more URLs for easy access but I am kind of on this 2 URL maximum program.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement, indeed it is, with syntax like this for example:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:C4;Sheet2!B1:D4},"select * order by Col1 desc"))
```

The `;` stacks one array above the other (`,` for side by side).

My confusions is with "URL Query Language" as what here is called Google Query Language (there is even the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-query-language) though IMO almost all those Qs belong on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - including this one, by my understanding!) is not confined to use with URLs.

In the example above the sheet references might be replaced with data import functions.

Comment: Hmm I have updated my question, but maybe you're right.